# Check and compare number of values of arraylist every 10sec using Android Service

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-service

I am facing a problem regarding service, How can I check and compare number of values of Arraylist in every 10 seconds using Android service?. currently I have this kind of setup:

- I have Service that checks Internet connection in every 10 secs, i would like to include the checking of Arraylist in that Service class.

What should obtain:

- If the number of values in Arraylist is the same after 10 secs, it would do nothing, but if there's a difference after 10 secs, the difference should be flashed as notification badge in my app

How can I do this?..Please help..Thanks in advance

EDIT:

For now I have this code in my NotifService.class:

This my timer for every 10seconds:

```
    CountDownTimer aCounter = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
    //TODO CountDownTimer
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

    }
    public void onFinish() 
    {


        NotificationVerfication task = new NotificationVerfication();
        task.execute(0);

        CheckMessage task1 = new CheckMessage();
        task1.execute(0);
        aCounter.start();



    }
};
```

and here's how I create a Push-notification:

```
    protected class CheckMessage extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> 
{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Integer... queue) {
        try {
            Context context =  getApplication().getApplicationContext();
            Log.i("testing",context.toString());

            IncomingMessageBadge();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("com.sonyericsson.home.action.UPDATE_BADGE");
            intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.ACTIVITY_NAME", "com.medilink.dontiacare_ecard.MainActivity");
            intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.SHOW_MESSAGE", true);
            intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.MESSAGE", 99);
            intent.putExtra("com.sonyericsson.home.intent.extra.badge.PACKAGE_NAME", "com.medilink.dontiacare_ecard");
            sendBroadcast(intent);                                                  

            Badge.setBadge(getBaseContext() , Integer.parseInt(GlobalVariablesClass.gMessages.toString()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("testing",e.toString());
        }
        return "COMPLETE!";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) 
    {


        if (run == 1) {
            if (unread > 0) 
            {
                NewCountMessage();
                existing = current;
                run = 2;
            }
        } else if (existing < current) 
        {
            existing = current;
            run = 2;
        }

        GlobalVariablesClass.gMessages = String.valueOf(unread);
        }



}
```

and Here is the Thing that I don't know what to put:

```
      private void IncomingMessageBadge(){

        //what should I put here?   

    }
```

Comment: show what you have tried

Comment: use `AlaramManager` to start the service every 10 minutes

Comment: see the EDITS aboive, I've posted some of my code. by the way, I put the number value of my arraylist in a global variable(its because my arraylist is been triggered in other class). Now, How can I compare the current arraylist and the arraylist's number value after 10 seconds?

Comment: If you run service in every 10 sec then it will cause a lots of battery drain

Comment: I made the service run when the app is in use but when it is minimized or closed, it also stopped. Now I need to compare the 2 arrays every 10 secs while the app is on my screen